# Как сделать проверку, если data[1] пустая, то записать пустое значение?

Tags: c#

У меня есть строки с номерами телефона типа:

1. 8(888)888888 доб. 888
2. 7(777)777777
3. 9(999)999999 доб. 999

Так вот когда я разбиваю строку

```
Split(new string[] { "доб." }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

все разбивается нормально. Значения я получаю, записываю так:

```
text = data[0]
```

но когда я буду записывать так:

```
text = data[1]
```

я получаю ошибку "Индекс находился вне границ массива". Понимаю, что ошибка во второй строке, но понятия не имею как сделать проверку, если data[1] пустая, то записать пустое значение.

Comment: Только условие, и как альтернатива - тернарное выражение. Например так `text = (data.Length > 1)?data[1]:"";`

Comment: Условием пробовал, не получилось.

Comment: Значит неверно условие записано было.

Comment: У вас во втором случае только один элемент будет в массиве после вызова `Split`.

Comment: Индекс находился вне границ массива - означает что в массиве один елемент, только проверка условием при таких операциях. Ну... там через Array.Copy можно "схитрить", или если написать свою обвертку на массив которая разрешит иметь доступ к несуществующим елементам за границами массива.

Comment: `if (data.Length > 1) { text = data[1]; } else {text = null; }`

Comment: И какая ошибка?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, получилось

Answer (score 0):

Проверять необходимо так если условие `if(data.Length < 2 )` выполняется, то `data[1]` пустая. Вот рабочий пример:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
            parsePhone("8(888)888888 доб. 888");
            parsePhone("7(777)777777");
            parsePhone("9(999)999999 доб. 999");
            parsePhone("");
        }

        public static void parsePhone(string v)
        {
            string[] data = v.Split(new string[] { "доб." }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            if(data.Length < 1){
                Console.WriteLine("Номер не указан");
            }else if(data.Length == 1 ){
                Console.WriteLine("Номер " + data[0]);
            }else{
                Console.WriteLine("Номер " + data[0] + " доб. " + data[1]);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Результат:

```
Hello, world!
Номер 8(888)888888  доб.  888
Номер 7(777)777777
Номер 9(999)999999  доб.  999
Номер не указан
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще так (не самый оптимальный, но вариант):

```
try
{
    text = data[1];
}
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
{
    text = string.Empty;
}
```